# Testcafe Vue Selectors can't grab Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm using Testcafe Vue Selectors to perform e2e testing on my Vue application but it looks like I can't grab any of my components:

```
1) An error occurred in getVue code:

      TypeError: Cannot read property '__vue__' of undefined
```

This is a sample test I have created:

```
import VueSelector from "testcafe-vue-selectors";
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Getting Started`
    .page `http://localhost:8081/`;

test('test totalValue format', async t => {
    const totalValue = VueSelector("total-value");

    await t
        .click("#total-value-toggle-format")
        .expect(totalValue.getVue(({ props }) => props.formatProperty)).eql(null)
});
```

The structure of my components tree is the following:

```
Root
|___App
    |___Hello
        |___TotalValue
```

And I import the component like this:

```
  "total-value": TotalValue,
```

Why is this not working?

EDIT: this is the page where I test the component

```
<template>
    <div class="hello">
        <div class="component-wrapper">
              <total-value
                  :value="totalValueValue"
                  :formatProperty="computedFormatNumber">
              </total-value>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>   
import TotalValue from "../../core/TotalValue";

export default {
    name: "hello",
    components: {
        "total-value": TotalValue,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            totalValueValue: 1000000,
            formatNumber: true,
            formatFunction: Assets.formatNumber,
        };
    },
    computed: {
        computedFormatNumber() {
            return this.formatNumber ? ["nl", "0,0 a"] : [];
        },

    },
};
```

Comment: Could you please provide full code (html, js) of the page on which this issue is reproduced?

Comment: I have added the page where the tests happen!

Comment: Cool!! Please, provide vue.js version too.

Comment: "vue": "^2.2.6" !

Comment: Done! I will follow the updates, thank you very much!

Comment: I've reproduced your issue. Currently, the testcafe-vue-selectors plugin doesn't support components loaded via vue-loader. 
I've created an issue https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-vue-selectors/issues/21 in the module repository. 
You can subscribe to track its progress.

Comment: What are you trying to grab exactly? Testcafe is testing the raw html generated by Vue, the same site that the user will see, so you cannot just grab components like e.g <total-value>...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a follow-up, we have fixed the issue described in this thread:

[Support component loaded via vue-loader](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-vue-selectors/issues/21)